# Updating multiple field in same table with different WHERE condition in mysql

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to update at the same time "QtyBalance" field in "bincard" table but using 2 different where conditions. currently i am using 2 query like this:

```
update `bincard` set `QtyBalance`= 80 where `BinId`= 65 
update `bincard` set `QtyBalance`= 20 where `BinId`= 66
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE `bincard` SET `QtyBalance` = 
   CASE 
      WHEN `BinId`= 65 THEN 80 
      WHEN `BinId`= 66 THEN 20 
      ELSE `QtyBalance`
   END
```

Comment: I'm not saying this is a bad query, it's probably the first I'd try, but I would test it's performance as I am not sure MySQL is smart enough to not go through the entire table. A `WHERE BinId IN (65, 66)` clause would help.